# htaccess rewrite for only root domain, selected files and selected folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Been fidling with it my self but I think I am doing it all wrong, please advice:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\-f
RewriteRule ^folder1(.*)$ https://newdomain.com$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^folder2(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^folder3(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/somefolder/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^page1\.html https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^page2\.html https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

If I request a page/folder for olddomain.com which is not in .htaccess it should not rewrite.

Does anyone have more skills in .htaccess than me?

Thanks,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should prepend an additional condition among the ones about newdomain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?newdomain\.com$ [NC]
```

Comment: But I have the following, is not this the same?

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]